# Control how a phone appears as a mass storage device from a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filesystems, usb

I'm writing a flutter app and I want to make the phone appear as a mass storage device when connected via USB to a host computer.  However, I want to control exactly what appears to be on the device.

In other words, if the application is running and the user connects the phone, the host computer  would not see the entire Android filesystem but rather it would appear that the root of the filesystem is a specific directory that determined by the application.

I'm not looking for specific how-to but I want to verify that this is possible and get a sense of what would be involved.  In general terms, how would I go about this?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Flutter, or really programming in general. I'm not sure which other Stack Exchange to recommend ([Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), perhaps) but I don't think it's on-topic here.

Comment: It is, at least, a programming related question.  It's behaviour that I want to program, not standard behaviour.   I guess my question is about whether this can be achieved with flutter and flutter/dart libraries or whether I'll have to resort to writing native device code.

Comment: The phone appearing as a mass storage device on a PC is a low-level device behavior. Flutter and Dart run within a VM that doesn't exist until an app is launched and initialized. Unless you are talking about using a client-server setup to emulate a connected mass storage device, there is little to no chance that you could do this in Flutter. But even beyond that, I am not aware of a method to programmatically control this behavior at all (unless you ran some low-level C/C++ code on a rooted device, maybe).

Comment: In either case, your question is not related to your own programming attempts to do this, but instead is asking if it's even possible and, if so, requesting a very general nudge in the right direction. As such, this is more of a "power user" question than a specific programming question, which is why I recommend you ask on the Android SE as you will get more targeted and higher quality answers there than here.